# Extracting spectral signal in a picture

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the following picture is a  doppler signal and I am having a pretty hard time extracting the envelop. Now i know there are mnay studies out there that have extracted such a signal but honestly I am relatively new to python

My main approach is to binarize the image and then apply contour extraction. But then I am not sure how shall I calibrate the image in a single pipeline by entering in y and x axis values (something like tkinter?)

[image]

Again, I have tried working with the common libraries like opencv, pillow, matplotlib.pyplot, numpy. Hope to utilize tesseract OCR and tkinter